# Solver Constraint to assign a penalty for binary changing from 0 to 1

Tags: excel, binary, excel-2010, linear-programming, solver

I am creating a production scheduling solver in which machine "X" can run in between 300 and 450 units, or the machine can be turned off.

My current constraint says.

```
300*d<=X<=450*d
```

"d" is binary constraint, and "X" is my decision variable. This constraint works fine for what i need it to. my solver is deciding how much to run the machine each day.

However, I need to apply a fixed cost penalty when d changes from 0 to 1. Essentially saying it costs `$26,000` to shut down a machine. I cannot figure out how to do this without getting an error saying my solver is not linear.

So if `d=1` on day 1 and `d=0` on day 2, I need to apply a fixed cost penalty of `$26000` in order to tell the machines to run as long as possible without shutting down.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can introduce a new variable defined over pairs of consecutive days, which will apply the following logic:

```
if d_t + d_t-1 = 1 then z_t = 1, otherwise z_t = 0
```

where `t` is the day index, `d_t` is the binary variable that shows if the machine is open or not in day `t`, and `z_t` is the newly introduced variable, that shows if there is a switch between days `t-1` and `t`.

To enforce this logic, you will need the following constraints:

```
z_t <= d_t + d_t-1
z_t >= d_t - d_t-1
z_t >= d_t-1 - d_t
```

**Why this works**

Here is the set of all possible values of `d_t`, `d_t-1` and `z_t`, as they result from the constraint above:

```
 d_t   |   d_t-1   |   z_t
--------------------------
  0    |     0     |    0
  0    |     1     |    1
  1    |     0     |    1
  1    |     1     |    {0, 1}
```

Note than in the last case, when `d_t` and `d_t-1` are both `1`, the constraints do not enforce `z_t` to a particular value. However, since you will have `$26,000*z_t` in your objective function, an optimal solution will pick up `z_t = 0` when it has the flexibility to do so, because it is cheaper than `z_t=1`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This {0,1} can be prevented by modeling this as a proper xor condition.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is some confusion in the question whether we have a penalty for a shutdown (d=1 followed by d=0) or a startup (d=0 followed by d=1). Here is a standard formulation for start-up and shut-down costs (used in many scheduling models). The other answer suggested a similar formulation, but that form is not much used in practice.

**Startup Cost**

We need a construct that forces a variable y(t)=1 only when d(t-1)=0 and d(t)=1. This can be done using

```
y(t) >= d(t) - d(t-1)
y(t) in {0,1}
```

In the objective you can add the term

```
26000 * sum(t, y(t))
```

(assuming minimization)

Details:

- d(0) is state of machine when we start the planning window (i.e. it is given)
- y(t) can be relaxed to `y in [0,1]`

**Shutdown Cost**

Very similar:

```
y(t) >= d(t-1) - d(t)
y(t) in {0,1}
```

The rest is identical.